# How to include test case owner name in the testng report

Tags: java, testing, automation, testng

I have a requirement where in I want to customize my testng report to show the test case owner's name in the report. I have a couple of .csv files. I read these files one by one and execute sequentially using data provider. These csv files belong to multiple users. Each Excel contains a separate column specifying the user name. I fetch this username and set as an attribute using ITestContext. But when I fetch this attribute I am getting null value in the report. If anybody worked on this earlier please provide your inputs

Comment: hi, how are running your users the test?

Comment: Could you share the code of your reporter and the way you put attributes in the context?

Comment: I got it. I am adding it through a listener.I am passing the param ITestContext to the test method using this context ,i am setting the owner name ctx.setAttribute("owner", ownerName); and also I am using a listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for ( String x : attribs ) {

```
            if (x.contains("owner")) {
                Field description = BaseTestMethod.class.getDeclaredField("m_description");
                description.setAccessible(true);
                String ownerName=((String)ctx.getAttribute( x )).trim();
                Reporter.log("ownerName at line 52 is :: "+ownerName);
                if("".equals(ownerName) || ownerName==null || ownerName.isEmpty()){
                    ownerName="Unable to Fetch Owner Name";
                }
                tr.setAttribute("owner", ownerName);
                description.set(tr.getMethod(),ownerName);

            }
```